# How do Ioop through some JSON and get particular key value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to JavaScript and im confused how to extract a particular key value from a JSON file:

```
var me = {"fcolors": ["blue", "green", "whitesmoke"],"fire": ["pink", "grey", "red"]};
```

i want only `fcolour` values

```
fcolour = [];
for (var key in me) {
    if (me[key] instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < me[key].length; i++) {
            console.log();
            fcolour.push(me[key][i])
        }
    }
}
```

i want result to be  `fcolour=["blue", "green", "whitesmoke"]`

thanks in advance and any comment is appreciated.....

Comment: `var fcolor = me['fcolors']`

Comment: yes but what if the json is coming from backend and json is very long .....it not efficient to extract like me.fcolors......

Comment: Your object can only have one key `fcolor`. You can't have multiple keys with the same name.

Comment: Andy is right. unless you have an Array of multiple objects..

Comment: What's inefficient about accessing me.fcolors? What's inefficient is to loop on the array and push back each value to a new array.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to loop to get its value since your json doesnt have array of `fcolors`:

`me.fcolors` will give you `["blue", "green", "whitesmoke"]`

[Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ucALvYRCaUXsVSCLtBAq?p=preview)

For Multiple objects:

```
var data = [{
  "fcolors": ["blue", "green", "whitesmoke"],
  "fire": ["pink", "grey", "red"]
}, {
  "fcolors": ["red", "white", "yellow"],
  "fire": ["black", "gray", "pink"]
}];

var fcolors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].hasOwnProperty('fcolors')) {
    fcolors.push(data[i].fcolors);
  }
}

console.log(fcolors);
```

`fcolors` contains array

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ucALvYRCaUXsVSCLtBAq?p=preview)

Comment: yes but what if the json is coming from backend and json is very long .....it not efficient to extract like me.fcolors ......

Comment: Do you have json in this format? `[{"fcolors": ["blue", "green", "whitesmoke"],"fire": ["pink", "grey", "red"]}, {"fcolors": ["blue", "green", "whitesmoke"],"fire": ["pink", "grey", "red"]}]` then only u need to worry about it else just go ahead with the above solution..

Comment: @AmoghAngadi Do you think looping is more efficient than to directly accessing it for a single key value paired JSON?

Comment: @VickyGonsalves consider using "concat"

Comment: If you're parsing from JSON you don't really need the `hasOwnProperty` clause because you know where the object's come from.

Comment: @Andy what if in some nodes in large JSON,  a key which you want to find doesnt exists?

Comment: It will return undefined.

Comment: true so why to forcefully push `undefined` in result array? if so I could have make use of `.map` instead of manual `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping JSON , when you can easily access given JSON as

```
me.fcolors; // It will give you ["blue", "green", "whitesmoke"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is a flat object, using the following will get the wanted value.

```
var jsonData = {fcolors: [...], fire: [...]};    

if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty('fcolors')) {
    var fcolors = jsonData.fcolors;
}
```

If you have multiple similar objects in the array, you could use the following to grab all the values.

```
var jsonData = [
    {fcolors: [...], fire: [...]},
    {fcolors: [...], fire: [...]},
    {fcolors: [...], fire: [...]}
];

var fcolors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    var current = jsonData[i];

    if (current.hasOwnProperty('fcolors')) {
        fcolors.push(current.fcolors);
    }
}
```

After which `fcolors` is a multidimensional array.